# Why doesn't my DLL work after I've compiled it with additional libraries, e.g curl, curlpp, cpprestsdk?

Tags: c#, c++, rest, curl, reverse-engineering

I'm creating a WPF C# application that handles the graphical part whilst also a C++ DLL for all the backend work.  Not only C# is used for graphical presentation, but also as a DLL injector. To communicate between the application, update stats and basic information, I chose to use pipes for a shared memory section. I have structured my program in a way that it doesn't do anything until it detects the program I want to inject my DLL into. Then I just send a test "helo" from the DLL to C# to make sure everything is working, and it does until I try to implement some kind of REST structure. I've got a simple server running that basically outputs some json upon GET request. I have never worked with additional libraries in C++ so the first thing I went and did was to look up for REST libraries and I found cpprestsdk by Microsoft. I went on the NuGet Package Manager and went on to install it and it was surprisingly easy to set it up, the DLL even compiled one the first try. Then I went to test it and it was not working. I went a step down and searched for cURL, because that always has been my go-to REST library. At first I went for a cURL wrapper called cURLpp, but it had the same issue at which point I decided to get cURL and not use the NuGet package manager and instead build the damn library myself from source up.

Upon further educating myself I just followed [these](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/winbuild/BUILD.WINDOWS.txt) instructions.
I put all the files in my workspace and changed project settings so that Visual Studio recognizes those files. So far so good. In my main.cpp file wrote

```
#include <curl\curl.h>
```

And upon building and testing the application it was running just fine. To have a bit tidier code I decided to create an additional class where all my GET requests would occur. I created HTTP_Controller.h where I had this code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "curl\curl.h"
class HTTP_Controller
{
public:
    HTTP_Controller();
    ~HTTP_Controller();
    int httpRequest();
private:
    static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
};
```

and then HTTP_Controller.cpp with the following:

```
#include "HTTP_Controller.h"

HTTP_Controller::HTTP_Controller()
{

}


HTTP_Controller::~HTTP_Controller()
{
}

int HTTP_Controller::httpRequest() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        std::string url = "http://localhost:4200/api";
        std::string data;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 1;
}

size_t HTTP_Controller::WriteMemoryCallback(void * contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * data)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;

    std::string * mem = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(data);
    mem->append(static_cast<char *>(data), realsize);

    return realsize;
}
```

And for context, this how my main.cpp looks like:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Header.h"
#include "HTTP_Controller.h"


void Init();
void voidMain();
void GetNationName();
void GetSteamID();

HTTP_Controller httpController;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hDllHandle,
    DWORD     nReason,
    LPVOID    Reserved)
{
    BOOL bSuccess = TRUE;
    if (nReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        Init();
    }
    return bSuccess;

}

void Init() {
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)voidMain, 0, 0, 0); // Creating separate thread for main method;

}

void voidMain() { // This is wherer the code actually starts
    HANDLE hPipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(_T("\\\\.\\pipe\\HyperPipe"),// Creates a Pipe Server so that dll can communicate with the client
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        4096,
        4096,
        0,
        NULL);

    BOOL isConnected = false;
    while (!isConnected) {
        isConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL); // Check if connected and connects to the pipe
    }

    std::string data = "helo"; // Message
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0; // Buffer
    WriteFile(hPipe, data.c_str(), data.length() * sizeof(char), &dwBytesWritten, NULL); // Sending hPipe message
    CloseHandle(hPipe); // Closing the handle after sending the message

    //httpController.httpRequest(); // Http request

}
```

I'm completely clueless, because without any code in HTTP_Controller.cpp the DLL runs just fine and throws "helo" through the pipe connection, but when I throw the slightest of cURL code it just dies and the pipe connections somehow hangs along with it. What confuses me the most is that even without calling any functions it somehow goes over HTTP_Controller.cpp and hangs even when I don't call any of the functions. I hope I have provided enough information.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] aka [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) that we can try ourselves?

Comment: If the code in the thread runs before `DllMain` has returned then you are in Microsoft-Undefined- Behaviour land.

Comment: Yes, give me a minute. Although I'm not sure how I'm going to provide the cURL library.

Comment: You need to supply explicit initialization and finalization functions and call them manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? Initialization for cURL functions ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've reproduced the project AND the problem to the best of my ability. I removed the GUI part and put all the important code into console c#. There are two sections in Program.cs where you will wanna change the victim process name. Also there should be a node js server running accepting GET requests from the DLL which I did not include. [project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LPkOLqBvai8IpXil8TpAkuGlZWNAg7xi)